# When I compile I get an error as "ask" cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: java

```
package mypackage; 

import java.util.Random;

interface SharedConstants
{
    int NO=0;
    int YES=1;
    int MAYBE=2;
    int LATER=3;
    int SOON=4;
    int NEVER=5;
}

class B implements SharedConstants
{

Random rand=new Random();

    int ask()
    {
        int prob=(int) (100 * rand.nextDouble());
        if (prob<30)
            return NO;
        else if(prob<60)
            return YES;
        else if(prob<75)
            return LATER;
        else if(prob<90)
            return SOON;
        else
            return NEVER;
    }

}

class c implements SharedConstants

{
    static void answer(int result)

    {
        switch(result)
        {
            case NO:
                System.out.println("No");
                break;
            case YES:
                System.out.println("Yes");
                break;
            case LATER:
                System.out.println("Later");
                break;
            case SOON:
                System.out.println("Soon");
                break;
            case NEVER:
                System.out.println("Never");
                break;
        }
    }
}

class interfacedem1

{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        System.out.println("prog starts");
        B dew=new B();
        answer(dew.ask);
        answer(dew.ask);
        answer(dew.ask);
        answer(dew.ask);
        System.out.println("prog ends");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`ask()` is a method, not a field. You need to call it as a method:

```
answer(dew.ask());
```

Also, you should probably replace your interface with an `enum`. It's better suited for storing enumerated constants:

```
enum Probabilities {
    NO, 
    YES, 
    MAYBE,
    LATER,
    SOON,
    NEVER;
}
```

And leave the class out from implementing the interface.

Comment: Was just going to suggest using an enum rather than using an interface to store constants avoiding that anti-pattern. +1

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're missing parentheses after `ask()`, e.g.:

```
answer(dew.ask());
              ^^
```

Secondly, `ask()` should probably be made `public`:

```
public int ask()
...
```

Comment: I guess they are in same package, so it is not needed to make it public.

Answer (score 0):

`answer()` static method so call it by using class name.
`ask()` is a method call it using "()".
Replace your

```
  answer(dew.ask);
```

with

```
  c.answer(dew.ask());
```